# Generate site Urls in Sharepoint 2016 without /sites after the domain name

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, managed-navigation

I have a site collection in SharePoint 2016 with the following URL.

```
https://xyz.com/sites/testclassic
```

and I have created a page `test.aspx` and with managed path it generates the following URL.

```
https://xyz.com/sites/testclassic/testpage
```

But I want to generate a URL like the following:

```
https://xyz.com/testpage
```

skipping the `sites/testclassic` portion in the URL.

How can I achieve that? Is it possible to skip the `/sites` portion in SharePoint? If Yes, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating [managed paths](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/define-managed-paths), specifically an **Explicit inclusion**. You would first need to define this managed path using central administration, then create a site collection using this. This would give your site the url `https://xyz.com/testpage`, and the home page of that site would be accessible using that url directly.

If you just want a single **page** to have this url you would have to create the page on the root site collection directly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot skip managed path `/sites/testclassic/`.

If you want a page like `https://xyz.com/testpage` , you must create the page under root site i.e. `https://xyz.com/`.